# EMR custom logging from mapper and reducer

Tags: logging, emr

Is it possible to have custom logs from mappers and reducers in EMR....
lets say I have a mapper which goes thru data and filters based on certain conditions

Mapper code (streaming)

- Look at input line
- If useragent is bad - LOG into a custom log
- else let it pass to reducer

How can I have the custom log written and get a consolidated log from all mappers in the log directory for that job.

Similarly if I want some logging done in reducer phase

- Work on the values for a key (e.g sort by datetime)
- if more than 20 events in one hour this is a bad user - LOG to custom log
  -else let it go to output

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultipleOutputs (new API) or MultiFileOutput (old API) to write to more than 1 output.
Write wanted records to the different log location. If you want 1 big log file you can merge them after the job is done.

Comment: Thanks..are there any examples that you can point me to. I tried searching but cannot find any..also I am using streaming job in Ruby for my EMR mapper and reducer

Answer (score 0):

To achieve multiple outputs look at 
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.3-alpha/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html

There is support in Java api to create multiple/named output files.

I was not able to find any way to do that in streaming code written in ruby.